Flask randomly returns user as not logged in when they are
I have a reasonably sized Flask project that works fine when run locally, however, when run via Apache or Nginx Server (locally hosted or externally hosted) users will occasionally be prompted that they are not logged in before getting redirected several times.
Below is the log showing the user being redirected from / to /login 9 times before being logged in.
[10:57:35] "GET /user/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 12277 "redacted/fleet" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET /user/1 HTTP/1.1" 302 770 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET /login?next=%2Fuser%2F1 HTTP/1.1" 302 736 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 787 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 745 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 789 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 747 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 789 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 749 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 793 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 751 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 793 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 751 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 794 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 752 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 795 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 753 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 795 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:37] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 752 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 797 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:37] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 756 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:37] "GET /user/1 HTTP/1.1" 302 822 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:37] "GET /login?next=%2Fuser%2F1 HTTP/1.1" 302 756 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4013 "redacted/user/1" 7.36"
[10:57:40] "GET /user/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 12273 "redacted/" 7.36"

The user does not need to log back in, and just refreshing the page a few times will work, however this issue keeps cropping up.
My user_loader function is as followed;
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return db.session.get(User, int(user_id))

Because I cannot replicate the issue reliably I am unable to provide an example.
I am using;

Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.1.1
Flask 3.0.2
Flask-Login 0.6.3
Flask-WTF 1.2.1
Nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Database is mysql Ver 8.0.35 with PhpMyAdmin hosted on the same machine.
Nginx configurations;
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name [REDACTED URL];
        
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.[REDACTED URL].log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.[REDACTED URL].log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/gunicorn/run/[REDACTED URL].sock;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /;
    };
}

Service configuration;
[Unit]
Description=Development
After=network.target

[Service]
User=gunicorn
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/gunicorn/[REDACTED URL]/[REDACTED NAME]
Environment="PATH=/home/gunicorn/[REDACTED URL]/[REDACTED NAME]/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/gunicorn/[REDACTED URL]/[REDACTED NAME]/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/gunicorn/run/[REDACTED URL].sock -m 007 wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Application code sample;
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = '[REDACTED]'
app.config['permanent_session_lifetime'] = timedelta(days=364)

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(
    app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1, x_host=1, x_prefix=1
)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

mail = Mail(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash('Already logged in!', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    email_login_form = EmailLoginForm()
    if 'email_login_submit' in request.form:
        if email_login_form.validate_on_submit():
            account_check = User.query.filter_by(user_email=email_login_form.user_email.data).first()
            if account_check is None:
                flash('Incorrect email or password!', 'danger')
                return redirect(url_for('login'))

            if not account_check.check_password(email_login_form.user_password.data):
                flash('Incorrect email or password!', 'danger')
                return redirect(url_for('login'))

            login_user(account_check, remember=True)

            return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template('login.html', email_login_form=email_login_form)
        
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')


Still looking for help on this please!

Is it possible to update this question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the behavior? How are you running your flask application -- via mod_wsgi, via a proxy, or some other mechanism? Please show us the specific configuration.

I am unsure of the rest of your syntax, but something that comes to mind Is ensuring that you are using the correct instance of "user". Ensure that you are either using the class throughout your code and not creating a static variable anywhere.

@larsks It is hard to reproduce the issue. When running a local development server, there is no issues. When I deploy the exact same code and use Apache or Ngnix then there is this random issue.
Currently using Ngnix and Gunicorn. What configuration would you like to see?

Do you have any code which handles a user not being logged in? Please share the same.

@Reuben could you include the configuration you have when you deploy, as well as a minimal flask-login code ?

@Reuben Please add whatever you can of the following I mention to your question: the version of nginx/apache used, any configs used and changes worth mentioning eg. wsgi,  code that handles the redirect from root to login(happens 9 times so maybe it was repeatedly called?) and finally any code you suspect is the cause.

If it happens during a POST request this might be the issue

@hehe There is no specific code that handles a user not being logged in, just using default implementation of '@login_required'.

@LiteApplication I have updated the original post with configuration and login code.

@AdityaDN I have updated the original post. Unfortunately it happens with both GET and POST requests, thank you for that link though was worth a try.

@Reuben, nothing seems wrong with the code can you try if request.method == "POST"  to seperate out  the post part and remove those urls to itself. That stray db.session.commit() is by mistake right? Finally try setting app.config['SECRET_KEY'] to something constant. IDK if it's none of these it might be something with the server config

@AdityaDN The stray commit is a mistake, I will update the original post. I have also tried changing secret keys as well. The main issue is that this can happy on any page, not just login. Also, the user is not actually logged out it just seems to say the user is not authenticated but then refreshing the same page 1 or 2 times then shows the user as authenticated without having to login again.

Managed to solve the issue. Turns out there was some development code left in;
with app.app_context():
    db.reflect()
    db.create_all()

Deleting this solved all the issues. Absolute nightmare to track down.
